# Bitwise shifting for Base64 encode function in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, base64, bit-shift

I'm trying to rewrite this javascript base64 encode routine in C++ (please note that it is non standard base64, and has a . at the beginning of the decode string).

Here is an example of the JS script - https://jsfiddle.net/km53844e/1/

The javascript base64 class I have posted beneath.

In the JS script it correctly converts CcnK to CMlaKA . However, in the C++ script, it incorrectly converts this to CMlaKr (not sure why, could it be something to do with the additional NaN statements in the JS script?

Or could it possibly be to do with the null terminated string in the C++ script? I notice that if I remove this I get CMlaKs which is still not correct.

I've tried adding the following to deal with the isnans but its not working.

```
  if (isnan(char_array_4[1])) {
            char_array_4[2] = char_array_4[1] = 64;
        } else if (isnan(char_array_4[2])) {
            char_array_4[3] = 64;
        }
```

C++ Code:

```
std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
  std::string ret;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  unsigned char char_array_3[3];
  unsigned char char_array_4[4];

  while (in_len--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
    if (i == 3) {
      char_array_4[0] = char_array_3[0] & 0x3f;
      char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xc0) >> 6);
      char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xf0) >> 4);
      char_array_4[3] = (char_array_3[2] & 0xfc) >> 2;

        if (isnan(char_array_4[1])) {
            char_array_4[2] = char_array_4[1] = 64;
        } else if (isnan(char_array_4[2])) {
            char_array_4[3] = 64;
        }

      for(i = 0; (i < 4) ; i++)
        ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i)
  {
    for(j = i; j < 3; j++)
    char_array_3[j] = '\0';

    char_array_4[0] = char_array_3[0] & 0x3f;
    char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xc0) >> 6);
    char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xf0) >> 4);
    char_array_4[3] = (char_array_3[2] & 0xfc) >> 2;

        if (isnan(char_array_4[1])) {
            char_array_4[2] = char_array_4[1] = 64;
        } else if (isnan(char_array_4[2])) {
            char_array_4[3] = 64;
        }

    for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
      ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

    while((i++ < 3))
      ret += '=';

  }

  return ret;

}
```

JS Code:

```
var Base64 = {
        _keyStr: ".ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+=",

    encode : function (input) {
        var output = [],
            chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4,
            i = 0;
        while (i < input.length) {
            chr1 = input[i++];
            chr2 = input[i++];
            chr3 = input[i++];

            enc1 = chr1 & 0x3f;
            enc2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0xf) << 2);
            enc3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 4);
            enc4 = chr3 >> 2;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output.push([this._keyStr.charAt(enc1),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc2),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc3),
                         this._keyStr.charAt(enc4)].join(''));
        }

        return output.join('');
    },

    decodeAsArray: function (b) {
        var d = this.decode(b),
            a = [],
            c;
                //alert("decoded base64:" + d);
        for (c = 0; c < d.length; c++) {
            a[c] = d.charCodeAt(c)
        }
                //alert("returning a");
        return a
    },

    decode: function( input ) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++)) ;

            chr1 = (enc1 | ((enc2 & 3) << 6));
            chr2 = (enc2 >> 2) | ((enc3 & 0x0F) << 4);
            chr3 = (enc3 >> 4) | (enc4 << 2);

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                        }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return (output);
    }

};
```

Comment: how is it base64 if it has 65 values? isn't that base65?

Comment: Well base65 then..

Comment: The `isNaN(chr2)` check means that the corresponding position was outside the input sequence. This happens when the length of the input sequence is not a multiple of 3. Your C++ code doesn't handle that case properly.

Comment: Yes, how would you suggest I handle that? I've already tried adding what I've updated the question with,but its not working.

Comment: Why does someone vote to close? There's nothing wrong with this question. I've given minimum examples etc/.

Comment: The implementation of `isnan(...)` doesn't work as expected certainly because you are using the same variables as input and output. In the JS code, the inputs are `chr<X>` variables and outputs are `enc<X>` variables. So, could you provide more c++ source code around the `isnan()` call ?

Comment: Hi J Piquard, sure, I have added where I think isnan statements should go in the C++ code, and I've updated the example, and also pasted the code inside the question with the isnan included. However, still it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when looking at your c++ code compared to the JavaScript the isnan() shall be as follow:

```
if (isnan(char_array_3[1])) { // char_array_3[1] = chr2
    char_array_4[2] = char_array_4[1] = 64; // char_array_4[2] = enc3 & char_array_4[1] = enc2
} else if (isnan(char_array_3[2])) { // char_array_3[2] = chr3
    char_array_4[3] = 64; // char_array_4[3] = enc2
}
```

> But the main problem is that the `isnan()` function is only dedicated to
>   floating-point value in C++ and doesn't have the same meaning as in
>   JavaScript.

Instead of using that `isnan()` function, replace the following part of `base64_encode()`:

```
  while (in_len--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
    if (i == 3) {
    ...
    if (isnan(char_array_4[1])) {
        char_array_4[2] = char_array_4[1] = 64;
    } else if (isnan(char_array_4[2])) {
        char_array_4[3] = 64;
    }
    ...
    for(i = 0; (i < 4) ; i++)
       ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
    i = 0;
  }
```

By the following one:

> 1- to prevent unexpected value when less than 3 bytes left in the
>   input buffer, force them to 0x00. Also before every next loop (`for(j=0;j<3;j++) char_array_3[j]=0x00;`).
>
> 2- when 2 bytes have been loaded from the input buffer `if (i == 2)`, the
>   last item of the output buffer is set to 64.
>
> 3- when only 1 byte has been loaded from the input buffer `if (i == 1)`,
>   the 2 last items of output buffer are set to 64.

```
  for(j=0;j<3;j++) char_array_3[j]=0x00; // initialize input array
  while (in_len--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
    if ((i == 3) || (in_len == 0)) { // encode when 3 bytes or end of buffer
    ...
    if (i == 1) { // instead of (isnan(char_array_4[1]))
        // both char_array_3[1] and char_array_3[2] are not defined
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_4[2] = 64;
    } else if (i == 2) { // instead of (isnan(char_array_4[2]))
        // char_array_3[2] is not defined
        char_array_4[3] = 64;
    }
    ...
    for(i = 0; (i < 4) ; i++)
       ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
    i = 0;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++) char_array_3[j]=0x00; // initialize input array
  }
```

The last error in the `base64_encode()` function in C++ compare to the JavaScript are in the output buffer computation for the intermediate items.
Instead of those following assignments:

```
  char_array_4[0] = char_array_3[0] & 0x3f;
  char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xc0) >> 6); // NOK
  char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xf0) >> 4); // NOK
  char_array_4[3] = (char_array_3[2] & 0xfc) >> 2;
```

Use the following ones:

> 1- When calculating `char_array_4[1]` (=**enc2** in JS), the entries
>   `char_array_3[0]` (=**chr1** in JS) and `char_array_3[1]` (=**chr2** in JS) are reversed.
>
> 2- When calculating `char_array_4[2]` (=**enc3** in JS), the entries
>   `char_array_3[1]` (=**chr2** in JS) and `char_array_3[2]` (=**chr3** in JS) are reversed.

```
  // JS =>  enc1 = chr1 & 0x3f;
  char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0x3f); // OK
  // JS =>  enc2 = (chr1 >> 6) | ((chr2 & 0xf) << 2);
  char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0xc0) >> 6) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2); // OK
  // JS => enc3 = (chr2 >> 4) | ((chr3 & 0x3) << 4);
  char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0x03) << 4); // OK
  // JS => enc4 = chr3 >> 2;
  char_array_4[3] = (char_array_3[2] & 0xfc) >> 2;
```

> **After those corrections, the conditional block `if (i)` is useless and shall be removed.**

Comment: Hi J. Piquard. I've tried as you suggested, as you can see in the c++ online compiler, and it doesn't work. It still gives me the same result as before.

Comment: @Ke. I have updated my answer after checking your added source code.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer, the problem was inside where the char_array_4 was made (not in the isnan statement). Although, I'm not quite sure why the isnan is needed in the javascript version. Is this because it's basically base65? since there are 65 chars in the script (including the . at the beginning)

Comment: @Ke. In my opinion, the `isnan()` function has been used just to detect the JavaScript `undefined` when reading data from the input buffer. I have also found errors in your `base64_decode()` function.

Comment: This is I think the best answer I've ever had on SO. Thanks so much J. Piquard